# Bigwedge superscript

Tags: symbols

I want the superscript to appear on slightly right in the bigwedge symbol as in the picture below:

[image]

But when I put $\bigwedge^{# A} X$ I get this

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can add a negative kern with `\mkern`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    With negative kern: \(\bigwedge^{\mkern-4mu\#A} X\)
    
    Without kern:\(\bigwedge^{\#A} X\)
\end{document}
```

You may need to adjust the amount depending on the font/font size.

Answer (score 2):

I add my proposal to have the superscript slightly to right like the image below using `\bigwedge\nolimits`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\bigwedge\nolimits^{{\#A}}X\]
\end{document}
```

Or with a negative space `\!`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\bigwedge\nolimits^{{\!\#A}}X\]
\end{document}
```

[image]